# Error during solution import in Visual Studio 2010 and when applying a web template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, sitetemplate

I'm trying to import a solution from a wsp-file into a SharePoint 2010 project in Visual Studio 2010. The solution file results from a site template I exported using the "safe as template" option of a website.

After selecting the solution file I exported and specifying the single items I want to import (I select all), Visual Studio starts to import the solution. When it finished with the last item it shows an error message saying:

> The SharePoint solution import operation completed, but with errors. As a result, the project may not deploy successfully.

To check whether the import was OK or corrupted I packaged the solution again and try to redeploy it via code by creating a new website collection, uploading the solution file (packaged with Visual Studio) as an user solution (sandboxed solution) to the website collection, activating all features of the solution and applying the web template to the site collection's root website. At the point where the template is applied it takes a long time till a SPException occurs with the following message:

```
<nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

The inner exception's message is not really better, it says:

```
<nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack><nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
```

StackTrace:

```
  [COMException (0x8107058a): <nativehr>0x8107058a</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack><nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +172

[SPException: <nativehr>0x80131600</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPGlobal.HandleComException(COMException comEx) +27257906
   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32 fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32 fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate, Int32& plWebTemplateId) +27639363
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(String strWebTemplate) +1218
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPWeb Web, String strWebTemplate, Nullable`1 bSharedNav, Boolean bOnTopNav, Boolean bOnQuickLaunch, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) +1870
   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickPage.BtnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +129
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

To validate that the error results from the solution import or packaging process I used the same code to create a website collection but this time using the original wsp-file which was not imported into Visual Studio and packaged again. And this time the web template can be applied without any error.

So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong when I imported the solution into Visual Studio or when I packaged the solution again.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the Visual Studio output window after the import, you'll likely see something like this in the "SharePoint Tools" output

Total number of items to import: 161
Total number of items imported successfully: 158
Total number of items not imported due to errors: 3

Then if you scroll up in the lines that are detailing what is being imported, you'll see descriptive errors of each item that failed.

In my case, it was

> Importing Module: _catalogswfpubApproval - SharePoint 2010_Features\ReviewWorkflowsSPD1033...
>   Error occurred while importing 'Module: _catalogswfpubApproval - SharePoint 2010_Features\ReviewWorkflowsSPD1033'
>
> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Which is clear enough.

I simply recreated the project with a project path close to the system root, and it imported successfully.